# Loop of Waypoint, attribut undefined after quit loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

Needed some waypoints stuff, I tried to make a loop which can help me to properly do it. (I tried before without loop, but make somethink like 8 / 10 var, this isn't really fun)

Actually, my code seems to be good, exept the fact than Waypoint doesn't work when I scroll.

btn-selected & btn-transparent are css class which help me to show to the user where he is on the page.

Here my code.

```
// array of id, my left menu
var tableMenu = new Array("#left-menu-top", "#left-menu-evo-details", "#left-menu-details-accordeon", "#left-menu-awesome", "#left-menu-prog-rerun", "#left-menu-features", "#left-menu-timeline", "#left-menu-upgrade");
// array of id, content section
var tableSection = new Array("top", "evo-details", "details-accordeon", "awesome", "prog-rerun", "features", "timeline", "upgrade");
// waypoint object array
var WaypointArray = {};
// array of offset
var OffsetWaypointArray = new Array("-50", "55", "55", "55", "55", "55", "55", "0");

function clearAllButtons() {

    for(value in tableMenu) {
        $(tableMenu[value]).removeClass("btn-selected");
        $(tableMenu[value]).addClass("btn-tranparent");
    }
}

function replaceClass(idLeftMenu) {
    clearAllButtons();
    $(idLeftMenu).removeClass("btn-tranparent");
    $(idLeftMenu).addClass("btn-selected");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('activated');
    for(var count=0; count < tableMenu.length; count++) {
        WaypointArray[count] = new Waypoint({
            element: document.getElementById(tableSection[count]),
            handler: function(direction) {
                clearAllButtons(),
                replaceClass(tableMenu[count]),
                console.log("you reached waypoint : "+tableSection[count]+" to : "+direction);
            },
            offset: OffsetWaypointArray[count]
        });
        console.log('counted '+count);
        //OffsetWaypointArray = {WaypointArray[count]};
    }

    //for(var count = 0; count < tableMenu.length; count++) {
    //  console.log(WaypointArray[count]);
    //}
});
```

After some scroll, console log give me that.

```
activated
scripts.js:32 you reached waypoint : top to : down
scripts.js:36 counted 0
scripts.js:32 you reached waypoint : evo-details to : down
scripts.js:36 counted 1
scripts.js:36 counted 2
scripts.js:36 counted 3
scripts.js:36 counted 4
scripts.js:36 counted 5
scripts.js:36 counted 6
scripts.js:36 counted 7
2scripts.js:32 you reached waypoint : undefined to : down
scripts.js:32 you reached waypoint : undefined to : up
scripts.js:32 you reached waypoint : undefined to : down
scripts.js:32 you reached waypoint : undefined to : up
2scripts.js:32 you reached waypoint : undefined to : down
scripts.js:32 you reached waypoint : undefined to : up
```

So it seems after quit the loop^, Waypoint are not defined anymore.
(Cause whereever I am when I refresh the page, the Waypoint work, and it show me at which page I am, but if I scroll, then I got errors)

Thanx for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic closure problem in JavaScript. The `count` variable you're using for the loop doesn't get captured at its current value when the asynchronous `handler` function gets run at a later date. Put another way, just because `count` was 4 when you created the waypoint doesn't mean it's value is 4 when it gets executed. In your example, `count` is going to be 8 when all your handlers execute and your array has nothing at index 8.

MDN has a [decent article on closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) that may help as a jumping off point.

Answer (score 0):

With the inspiration from @imakewebthings, I just resolve the similar problem like this:

```
// create a function as the "environment", provide the needed parameter to it, return the waypoint object, this will ensure, when the action is completed, it will return the result one by one later in the loop.

function createWayPoint( eleID, index ){
  return new Waypoint({
    element: document.getElementById( eleID ),
    handler: function(direction) {
      hightlight( index );
    }
  });
};

window["wp"] = []; // putting it in global object for testing purpose
for( var i = 0; i < $("#floor-navigator li").length; i++ ){
   createWayPoint( "floor" + (i + 1).toString(), i )
   console.log(i);

   // store it one by one and you can see, they are successfully created
   window["wp"].push( createWayPoint( "floor" + (i + 1).toString(), i ) );
};
```

Many thanks and hope this can help other people with similar difficulties.